# Will the output of .toLocaleDateString change depending on the Time Zone of the user?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, kendo-ui

I'm writing some JavaScript for one of our database tables  for CRUD functions, and one of the ID fields used for identify a data item is a date. When pulling this data in using AJAX, it comes in the full JavaScript data format: `Thu Apr 25 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)`.

This is causing problems since when it is sent off, Kendo UI changes it to UTC, and in this case, the day changes to the 24th of April, meaning our backend code can't find the record.

What I've done to try to fix this is change this field when it comes in using `.toLocalDateString`. This has fixed my problem, as it seems to just chop off the information about the timezone, and just gives me `DD/MM/YYYY`, which the backend accepts.

My question is: will this have the intended effects (ignore the timezone and just give me the date) if the program is used in, say, Eastern USA.

Since I am in Britain, and our timezone is currently British Summer Time, which is the timezone in which the original data pulled in was in, is this only working since I am in BST? If I was in EST, which is 5 or 6 hours behind, would `.toLocaleDateString` cause the day to go back 1?

I've looked in the documentation and all it says is 'Using local conventions', and the meaning of this is unclear to me.

**Edit:**
I am getting `Mon May 13 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)` back from the AJAX request. When I send this back off, I stringify the data, and it stringifies to this: `"2019-05-12T23:00:00.000Z"`, which is in UTC, causing the problem.

Comment: Yes. Thats the whole point of `Locale` in `LocaleDateString` Refer [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Comment: The default value returned by *toLocaleDateString* is essentially implementation dependent, you should not expect it to be in any particular format or to be correctly parsed by other built–in parsers.

Comment: @Rajesh If i specify the Timezone as BST, will it counteract this?

Comment: @Mahogany there should be a better way to handle it. If you still want to pursue this path, linked docs has an example of specifying a timezone. Also, I checked Kendo's docs. It does not seen to convert to UTC. Can you please share the code where you accept date from kendo?

Comment: @Rajesh in [this](https://www.telerik.com/forums/date-in-grid-is-off-by-1-day) forum thread, the admin states that the timezones are converted to UTC.

Comment: @Mahogany By default, Kendo does not changes to UTC. In the attached forum, what they are suggesting you is to fallback to UTC. That means you will have to convert your local date to UTC on both Client and Server, and process accordingly. Idea is to choose a common timezone and UTC is more appropriate. So make sure you do your conversions both on SERVER and CLIENT

Comment: @Rajesh please see my edit.

Comment: @Mahogany Please notice **GMT+0100** in the date you get. That is not UTC. Convert date to UTC before sending value from server

Comment: @Rajesh I can't alter data sent from the server, as the field is an ID field, and if the date changes, it wouldn't be able to find it to make changes to that record.

Comment: @Mahogany - The format you're showing here is the output of the `Date` object's `toString` function - which some (but not all) browsers will show implicitly when you pass a `Date` object to `console.log`.  Most likely your ajax call is returning a different format and somewhere that string is being parsed it to become a `Date` object.  Please verify the actual string or numeric format passed in the HTTP response of your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

The toLocaleDateString() method of Date instances returns a string with a language-sensitive representation of the date portion of the specified date in the user agent's timezone. In implementations with Intl.DateTimeFormat API support, this method simply calls Intl.DateTimeFormat. from mdn